# VBA Solution for removing all text but dd-mmm-yyyy;dd-mmm-yyyy@Basic

Tags: excel, date

So one of our columns in excel has data in a cell that has subscription data, date start and date end data.

So for example:

14-Nov-2017;08-Jan-2018;Intermediate,11-Jan-2018;;Basic, 12-Jan-2018;;Basic

I would like to remove the 14-Nov-2017;08-Jan-2018;Intermediate in this example and save anything with basic value and its dates. Also coma Separated values between each data chunk.

Comment: I feel like you could accomplish this using regex on Windows powershell. Try that out and ask the question again in a more specific manner.

Comment: are the different "chunk" of things to keep or remove always seperated by a comma? Is the criteria to keep one of those chunks just that it must take the form `dd-mon-yyyy;;Basic`? When you say "No programming" are you saying no VBA as well?

Comment: they are always seperated with a coma. I didn't even know what VBA was until I just looked it up so in a sense that could make my answer. Changed my question, now I'd prefer a vba answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a couple of things:

1. The chunks we are looking at to keep/replace are separated by a comma
2. The form of the chunks we wish to keep are always `<date>;;Basic`

In excel press Ctrl+F11 to bring up VBE (where we write VBA or "macros")
Right click, in the Project-VBAProject pane in the upper-left, on your workbook and select "Insert>>Module". This will create Module1 in the Modules folder.

Now paste in the following UDF:

```
Function cleancell(strCell As String) As String
    For Each el In Split(strCell, ",")
        If IsDate(Split(el, ";")(0)) And Split(el, ";")(2) = "Basic" Then
            cleancell = IIf(cleancell = "", cleancell, cleancell & ",") & el
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

This will give your workbook a new custom formula (User Defined Formula). Save your workbook to insure the UDF is ready to go.

Assuming you have value `14-Nov-2017;08-Jan-2018;Intermediate,11-Jan-2018;;Basic, 12-Jan-2018;;Basic` in Cell `A1`, then in `A2` you can use the new formula:

```
 =cleancell(A1)
```

This will spit out:

```
 11-Jan-2018;;Basic,  12-Jan-2018;;Basic
```

In use:
[image]